# Duplicate but Still cannot understand the concept?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, personal-pronouns

Personal pronouns are confusing. Which one is correct?

> She went with him and I.

Or

> She went with him and me.

-

> Susan went with Don and "I" to the office.

Or

> Susan went with Don and "me" to the office.

Comment: You're right. Your teacher is wrong, but this non-standard usage is becoming increasingly common.

Comment: ... It's called a 'hypercorrection'.

Comment: Ask your teacher if they would say "She went with I" !

Comment: As Kate suggests, at least for simple cases one can check validity by omitting the "Don and" portion of the sentence and seeing how it "sounds".  You would not say "She went with I", you'd say "She went with me".  Your teacher is wrong.

Comment: A very easy rule to remember: after a ***preposition***, use the object of a preposition. For example: for me, them, us, him, her, and of course,  you, which doesn't vary. This particular grammatical point could not be easier. [sigh]

Comment: Thank you so much. I was reading an article about this a couple of minutes ago, and it is much easier than I thought. Thank you all for explaining this to me.

Answer (score 3):

"She went with Don and me" I think is the correct sentence. Grammatically speaking, "me" is a Company Complement. "I" is a subject.
For example: "Don and I should go with her" is correct because "I" is subject.